# How to get count of duplicate keys using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have following Json structure-

```
[{
 cName:"A",
"datastores" : [ 
    {
        "status":"unused"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "datastore1",
         "status":"used"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "onNetApp7m",
         "status":"used"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "datastore1",
         "status":"used"
    }
    ],
},
{
 cName:"B",
"datastores" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "dsn",
         "status":"used"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "dsn",
         "status":"used"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "datastore2",
         "status":"used"
    }
    ],
}
]
```

I want to find only such names from array/list "ds" whose count is greater than 1.
I want following output-

```
[{
"cName":"A",
"name" : "datastore1",
"count": 2
},
{
"cName":"B",
"name" : "dsn",
"count": 2
}]
```

Currently, for getting count, I am handling it in my code logic.
Is it possible to get count from query itself using mongo??

Comment: `ds` has been changed to `datastores` - was it a typo?

Comment: @BatScream  yes it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate as below:

- `Unwind` the `datastores` array.
- `Group` the records by the `cName` and the `datastores` name fields.
  Get the `count` of records in each group.
- The `group` we need to match is now the group having `count > 1`.
- `Project` the required fields.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$datastores"},
{$group:{"_id":{"cName":"$cName","name":"$datastores.name"},"count":{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"cName":"$_id.cName","name":"$_id.name","count":1}}
])
```